# XPM Gui extensions - customize the content library display

Tags: experience-manager, gui-extensions

I'm currently working on an XPM GUI extension that customizes the component library to insert content via XPM

[image]

I've found out that this list of components gets rendered by an XSLT stylesheet called DrillDownlistTemplate.xslt that can be found here : [tridion-install-dir]\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\DrilldownList\

Currently, i've almost achieved what I want to do by editing the  DrillDownlistTemplate.xslt file itself, **which is off course not the correct way to do it,** as it's not supported to change any core tridion files.

I'm wondering if there is a way to override this xslt file (replace it by our own) to do some custom rendering.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you changing in the library? :-)

Comment: We want to show a specific thumbnail per component to visualize the contents of the available components. For this, i've written a data extender that adds the icon to display per component. I now just need to change the xslt to make it render the new icon, instead of the default one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: ["Extensibility | XSLT inclusion"](http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2013/04/extensibility-xslt-inclusion/)

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I'll try it and i'll let you know when I got it to work

Comment: You should copy the relevant bits from the link in here -- as the link might not be accessible in the future.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but it looks like this xslt inclusion is not added to every xslt file. For example, i manage to add it to this one "WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Controls/Gallery/GalleryTemplate.xslt", but not to this one (the one I need to extend) "/WebUI/Core/Controls/DrilldownList/DrilldownListTemplate.xslt"

Comment: Extending core resources is bit more tricky. However, example from the article extends core resources as well. Check link below to GitHub project. I think the moment is to set *<ext:editorextension target="">*

Comment: thanks, setting the target="" instead of target="CME" or target="SiteEdit" worked indeed.